# Entity Framework 6 - Database First - Remove table names with prefixes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an existing database with tables that have a prefix

ex) 
 - px_mytable1
 - tx_mytable1

When I use entity framework to generate models from my database, the prefix is included in the model name..

ex)
 - public partial class px_mytable1
 - public partial class tx_mytable1

How do I configure entity framework to remove the prefix from the model name?

Note: I am using an .edmx file to generate models from the database schema.

Comment: are you using database first approach where you import everything to an edmx file, or do you use the tools to reverse engineer to code first? If alternative 1, there should be some sub-files of the edmx that generates the models from the database model, that can be changed to generate stuff in a different manor. If alternative 2, you can add your own mapping classes, so map between a code first model and your db-field. Docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088641/custom-convention-for-table-with-prefix-entity-framework  or at the least, an intro to custom "Convention"'s !

Comment: @granadaCoder isn't that code first?

Comment: @thsorens using edmx file.

Comment: https://github.com/dioptre/edmx/tree/master will probably handle it. Not pretty though, but the edmx approach rarely is;)

Comment: You didn't mention edmx in your original question.  Just an fyi, I don't know of anyone who uses edmx anymore.  The Poco/Fluent-Mapper is just so much cleaner IMHO.

Comment: @granadaCoder thanks for the tip!  Fluent-Mapper is code first right?

Comment: Yes.  edmx are good for proof of concepts...but once its gets on a "real", they are hard to open and manage.  the best way to learn (imho) poco mapping is to take a small database (that you know well) (or create one that has 1:N, M:N (no attributes on relationship), M:N (attributes on the relationship), a lookup table..........and reverse poco engineer it.  internet search for "entityframework reverse poco generator"  I learned more about poco mapping doing this in about 2 hours then I did ready alot of tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do some changes to the t4 template files(.tt).
first o all in yourModelName.tt file add the following variable in in of the 5,6,7 ... 13 lines.

```
var tablePerfix="px_";
```

FInd the following code

```
 `<#=codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty)#>`
```

and replace it with

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty).Replace(tablePerfix,"")#>
```

---

Find the following code

```
foreach (var entity in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>
(itemCollection))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(code);
#>
```

replace it with

```
foreach (var entity in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate<EntityType>
(itemCollection))
{
    fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name.Replace(tablePerfix,"") + ".cs");
    BeginNamespace(code);
```

---

Apply `.Replacy(tablePerfix,"")` like following to remove prefix from entities.

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity).Replace(tablePerfix,"")#>
// ...
public <#=code.Escape(entity).Replace(tablePerfix,"")#>()
// ...
this.<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty).Replace(tablePerfix,"")#> = new HashSet<<#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType()).Replace(tablePerfix,"")#>>();
```

if you have 2 prefixes for the tables in the DB you should use Replace method twice for each prefix

Finally, in yourModelName.Context.tt file add a variable called `tablePrefix`, and change following code

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.DbSet(entitySet)#>
```

To

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.DbSet(entitySet).Replace(tablePerfix,"")#>
```

Comment: I know it's old answer and even solution with edmx, but I have project with edmx. I would like to generate model based on db with replacting prefix "TBL_" to empty string. I did all the steps above, but names weren't changed. What can I miss? Thanks

Comment: try to follow these steps again. I'm guessing you didn't apply your changes in the codes. try right-click and `generate codes` (Can't remember the exact name). let me know if you still have the problem

Comment: Hi! I made to generate entity classes with replaced prefix, but still it appears like not modified table-names inside of edmx model

Comment: It won't change table names in the edmx model, it will change them in c# auto-generated files. I don't have any idea how you can change them in the edmx model.

Comment: is it possible to change names in edmx?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure

Answer (score -2):

You can use the fluent API or data annotations to configure your classes so Code First can map the relationships between your tables. one way is to
Override the `OnModelCreating` Method on Your `DbContext` Class, and there you can map your Classes To your Database table names

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>().ToTable("Table1");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Class2>().ToTable("Table2");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Class3>().ToTable("Table3");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

[This link may help you](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx)